# MySql SELECT Query for Multiple Keywords across Multiple Fields

Tags: php, mysql, select, match, against

I need some help for the logic of a `SELECT` query and hope someone can give me a better idea than the one I have.

I have a table like this:

```
 +---------+----------+---------+-----------+
 |      id | model    | variant | category  |
 +---------+----------+---------+-----------+
 |       1 | round    | black   | fruit     |
 |       2 | square   | white   | vegetable |
 |       3 | flat     | red     | meat      |
 |       4 | round    | black   | meat      |
 +---------+----------+---------+-----------+
```

Users will be allowed to do a search on this table by entering one or more keywords.

The query I have right now does a `MATCH` on all entered keywords `AGAINST` each field and I get rows that match ANY of the keywords.
So if the input is "round meat", the result will be rows 1, 3 and 4:

```
SELECT v.*, vt.color 
            FROM tbl_items 
            AS v 
            LEFT JOIN tbl_apple 
            AS vt 
            ON v.id = vt.v_id 
            WHERE ( 
            MATCH (v.model) AGAINST ('keyword1 keyword2' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
            OR MATCH (v.variant) AGAINST ('keyword1 keyword2' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
            OR MATCH (v.category) AGAINST ('keyword1 keyword2 ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ) 
            AND v.type = 4
```

However, I need to only return the rows that contain ALL keywords. The keywords might be contained in any of the three columns.

So if the user enters "round meat", only row 4 is returned.

My current idea is very simple and probably not very good (I expect some performance issues for multiple keywords):

```
SELECT v.*, vt.color 
            FROM tbl_items 
            AS v 
            LEFT JOIN tbl_apple 
            AS vt 
            ON v.id = vt.v_id 
            WHERE 
                ( 
                     (v.model = 'keyword1' 
                   OR v.variant = 'keyword1' 
                   OR v.category = 'keyword1'
                     ) 
        AND 
                     (v.model = 'keyword2' 
                   OR v.variant = 'keyword2' 
                   OR v.category = 'keyword2'
                     )
                 ) 
            AND v.type = 4
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: With complex keyword searching requirements like this, I'd suggest using a dedicated search tool like Sphinx or Lucene -- it'll add a bit of complexity up-front to your system, but the payoff in terms of performance and flexibility will be huge.

Comment: Sphinx is good suggestion, thank you. However, the search function I am trying to integrate is just small part of the entire search (which is already available), so I need something simpler. Else, quite valid advice if such search is meant to be core functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a whole code that may helps you."
You can modify query according to database or requirements.

```
    <?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'test');
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $search_text = $_POST['text'];

    $values = explode(" ",$search_text);

    $query = "";
    foreach($values as $value)
    {
        $query .='concat(model,varient,category) like "%'.$value.'%" AND ';
    }

    $query .= "1=1";

    $query = "select * from tbl_items where ".$query."";
    $result= mysqli_query($db,$query);
    echo '<table>';
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['model'].'</td><td>'.$row['varient'].'</td><td>'.$row['category'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
}
?>
<form method="post" name="form">
<input type="text" name="text" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">  
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I like that you posted an entire solution rather than just part of it :) I ended up combining my idea with parts of your code and as of now it seems to be working quite good! Thanks again!